# Spring Security Preauthentication Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am attempting to configure a PreAuthenticationFilter in a spring web application. I am following this [official guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/reference/preauth.html), and looking at section

> 18.2.1 Request-Header Authentication (Siteminder)

Here is my security.xml file, that outlines my beans and configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd" 
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="com.MyFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
      <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
      </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/**" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/main/data" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATORS')" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="any" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

Basically, the only thing I am chaning from the guide is my filterId and class. Everything else is the same.

The error I am getting is this:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined
```

What am I missing here? That class is already in the Spring Jar, which is in my project, and can be imported into any class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a bean `userDetailsService` to set a property with `name userDetailsService` in the below line.

```
<beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
```

So you should have declared a bean with id `userDetailsService` some where in your security.xml file as below. But I don't see any such bean.

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.xxx.xxx">
</bean>
```

For example you have a ref bean `preauthAuthProvider` and you have it referencing to

```
<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
```

Comment: sigh, you are correct. I missed the small footprint denoting that you have to implement your own userdetailservice. In grails 3 plugin, that does the same thing, you do not, thus a small discrepancy there caused the issue.